# Need Value from Simple Javascript Addition Multiplication

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but I am just trying to get a total price to display after you make a selection. I want to take the value of the selection and multiply it by 100 and then use the updatetotal function to display the total.

```
// Collect Data & Prices To Update Dynamic Prices
 var pricechecking=document.getElementById('howmanyaccts')value.trim();
 var pricepaypal=document.getElementById('howmanyacctspaypal')value.trim();

 var pricecheck = pricechecking * 100;
 var pricepay = pricepaypal * 100;

 function updateTotal() {

 var ThePrice = pricecheck + pricepay;

 $('#TotalPrice').text('$' + ThePrice + '.00');
 }

 $(function () { $('.DoPricing').click(updateTotal); });
```

MY HTML IS:

```
<form action="http://linktomyactionpage" method="post" >
 <p>How many accounts to pay by check?</p>
 <select name="howmanyaccts" id="howmanyaccts" class="DoPricing">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>

 <p>How many accounts to pay by paypal?</p>
 <select name="howmanyacctspaypal" id="howmanyacctspaypal" class="DoPricing">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>

 <p>Total: <span id="TotalPrice">$0.00</span></p>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

What if I simplified the code? Brought the 00.00 to the text and no multiplication?

```
 // Collect Data & Prices To Update Dynamic Prices
 var pricechecking=document.getElementById('howmanyaccts').value.trim();
 var pricepaypal=document.getElementById('howmanyacctspaypal').value.trim();

 function updateTotal() {

     var ThePrice = pricechecking + pricepaypal;

     $('#TotalPrice').text('$' + ThePrice + '00.00');
 }

 $(function () { $('.DoPricing').click(updateTotal); });
```

HERE IS WHAT I GOT TO WORK:

```
 // Collect Data & Prices To Update Dynamic Prices
 var pricechecking=document.getElementById('howmanyaccts').value.trim();
 var pricepaypal=document.getElementById('howmanyacctspaypal').value.trim();

 function updateTotal() {
 var pricecheck = parseInt($('#howmanyaccts').val(), 10);
 var pricepay = parseInt($('#howmanyacctspaypal').val(), 10);

     var ThePrice = pricecheck + pricepay;

     $('#TotalPrice').text('$' + ThePrice + '00.00');
 }

 $(function () { $('.DoPricing').click(updateTotal); });
```

Comment: Error here `.getElementById('howmanyacctspaypal')value`

Comment: For starters, you're writing `getElementById(...)value` at two places where it should be `getElementById(...).value`. If you want more detailed help, consider giving more detail about what problem you're facing.

Comment: @David - I'm not getting a total

Comment: I changed the .value and now the first dropdown gives me a value of $200.00 no matter what I select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/F3HbJ/

```
$(function () {
    $('.DoPricing').change(function () {
        var total = 0;
        $('.DoPricing').each(function () {
            total += parseInt($(this).val()) * 100;
        });
        $('#TotalPrice').html('$' + total);
    });
});
```

The event handler is `.change()` for a select. Then you loop through the `parseInt` values of each select that you multiply by 100.

Comment: Yeah I just figured that out too! Thanks!

Comment: Your code works better! My code didn't work on my site. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> Here is working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wZCer/)
>
> use like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var pricechecking = $($("#howmanyaccts")[0].selectedOptions).attr("value");
        var pricepaypal = $($("#howmanyacctspaypal")[0].selectedOptions).attr("value");

        function updateTotal() {
            var pricecheck = parseInt($('#howmanyaccts').val(), 10);
            var pricepay = parseInt($('#howmanyacctspaypal').val(), 10);

            var ThePrice = pricecheck + pricepay;

            $('#TotalPrice').text('$' + ThePrice + '00.00');
        }

        $('.DoPricing').change(updateTotal);
    });
```